# Nested Json retrieval

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the JSON in this format:

```
{
  "child": {
    "data": 45,
    "child": {
      "data": "12",
      "child": {
        "data": "23",
        "child": {
          "data": "11",
          "child": {
            "data": "56",
            "child": {
              "data": "76",
              "child": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is dynamically using jQuery get the data of each child and retrieve on the page

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: just loop through each child object starting from parent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a recursive function

```
var retriveData = function (child) {
  console.log(child.data)// here you can show on page with some function like div.append
  if(Object.keys(child.child).length>0)
    retriveData(child.child);
}
```

And call it like bellow.

```
retriveData(data.child);
```

I've used your sample data as variable `data`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/qvwpp/2/)